# Migration from environment to master Wordpress

Tags: migration

Is there any way to migrate the project from one environment to another? You mean exactly the difference between them?

Let's say I have a plugin in dev that is not in the master, can I somehow transfer it with all its settings from dev?

We use ftp.

Comment: Use a plugin for for that.. I use `Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin` for all my migration from dev to live.

Comment: I need the database in the master to change only within the new plugins, but all posts and pages remain. Plug-in can do that?

Comment: Nope, how do you save your plugin data in DB? If you are using a custom table, you can manually export that from phpMyAdmin and import in live.